# how to stop the variation of devexpress textbox's width

Tags: devexpress

i have web form running in asp.net & c#.net,

The form has a devexpress aspxtextbox  and the another ordinary  textbox with a button.

The scenario is enter a text longer than the width of the text box  in the ordinary text box.

on clicking the button it enters the text in to devexpress aspxtextbox ,increasing the width of the devexpress aspx text box inspite of width given as 50 px.

how to maintain the fixed width for devexpress aspx text box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

e adding the property native ="true" solved out the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Dev Express has this problem in IE7 Document Standards Mode, and usually the reply you'll get from them is something like "The control is designed this way." This doesn't help us in IE7. The problem isn't only with ASPxTextBox, but also happens with others, such as ASPxComboBox.

While making the control native will work, you lose various styling, etc.

Here is another way that keeps the control non-native:

**javascript**:

```
function SetInnerWidth(s, e) {
        s.widthCorrectionRequired = true;
        s.AdjustControl();
}
```

**devex control**:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox …… >
.
.
<ClientSideEvents Init="SetInnerWidth” />
.
.
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```